# Cross browser tracking

Tags: anonymity, cookies

Say I have one (non tor) browser open and visit a site like Gmail, then using a tor browser, use an email services associated with an alias. Using either cookies or some other mechanism could those two accounts become linked?

Answer (score 1):

Websites can detect that you are using Tor because there are lists of every Tor exit node (just compare IP Addresses and *voila!*) Because Gmail (i.e. Google) knows you are using Tor, they know you are not really the client you say you are. When Google sends you the email about a login from a different location, and you don't reset the password, you are confirming that the login was you.

Cookies are only cross browser if they are [Local Share Objects (LSO)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_shared_object) (i.e. Flash cookies). If the Tor Browser does not allow Flash, the cookies will not carry over to the browser. Look at [your Flash Player settings](https://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/settings_manager07.html) to see and manage your flash cookies.

I hope this answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible. One of the simpliest techniques is called [Evercookie](https://github.com/samyk/evercookie) and it is just one of the "persistent cookies" family. It's based on system-wide stored data, like HTTPS protocol enforcement cookies and so forth.